# How to avoid "org.apache.http.NoHttpResponseException" when writing to s3

Tags: java, apache-spark, amazon-s3

Working in spark (2.11) over s3 (java, spark standalone)

I get org.apache.http.NoHttpResponseException: my-bucket.s3.amazonaws.com:443 failed to respond
 when trying to call

the rdd is big (~20m records)

I have the following code -

```
myRdd.saveAsTextFile(myDir);
```

and When running it, I have 2 problems -

1) If it works, it's very slow
2) About ~10% of the times I call it, I get the exception

> 2019-02-18 18:51:42,820 [my-app] [s3a-transfer-shared--pool9-t331] INFO  com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient- Unable to execute HTTP request: my-bucket.s3.amazonaws.com:443 failed to respond
>   org.apache.http.NoHttpResponseException: my-bucket.s3.amazonaws.com:443 failed to respond
>       at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:143)
>       at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:57)
>       at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractMessageParser.parse(AbstractMessageParser.java:261)
>       at org.apache.http.impl.AbstractHttpClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(AbstractHttpClientConnection.java:283)
>       at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(DefaultClientConnection.java:259)
>       at org.apache.http.impl.conn.ManagedClientConnectionImpl.receiveResponseHeader(ManagedClientConnectionImpl.java:209)
>       at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.doReceiveResponse(HttpRequestExecutor.java:272)
>       at com.amazonaws.http.protocol.SdkHttpRequestExecutor.doReceiveResponse(SdkHttpRequestExecutor.java:66)
>       at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.execute(HttpRequestExecutor.java:124)
>       at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryExecute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:686)
>       at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:488)
>       at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.doExecute(AbstractHttpClient.java:884)
>       at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:82)
>       at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:55)
>       at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:384)
>       at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:232)
>       at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(AmazonS3Client.java:3528)
>       at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.copyObject(AmazonS3Client.java:1507)
>       at com.amazonaws.services.s3.transfer.internal.CopyCallable.copyInOneChunk(CopyCallable.java:143)
>       at com.amazonaws.services.s3.transfer.internal.CopyCallable.call(CopyCallable.java:131)
>       at com.amazonaws.services.s3.transfer.internal.CopyMonitor.copy(CopyMonitor.java:189)
>       at com.amazonaws.services.s3.transfer.internal.CopyMonitor.call(CopyMonitor.java:134)
>       at com.amazonaws.services.s3.transfer.internal.CopyMonitor.call(CopyMonitor.java:46)
>       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Any idea how can I resolve it?

thanks, nizan

Comment: have a look here(also lot of usless stuff in that posts but you may find what you need ...): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21237391/apache-httpclient-4-3-setting-connection-idle-timeout  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6764035/apache-httpclient-timeout https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9873810/using-apache-httpclient-how-to-set-the-timeout-on-a-request-and-response